# Unity error CS1520: Method must have a return type

Tags: unity3d

```
    public bool onGround = True;

    OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if(other.tag == "Player"){
            onGround = True;
        }
        else{
            onGround = False;
        }
    }
```

Хотел сделать проверку на то, касаеться ли игрок земли с помощью специального объекта с галочкой IsTrigger. Написал такой код, для проверки на соприкосновение выдает эту ошибку. Кто знает с чем это связанно и что тут может быть не так?

Comment: void допишите перед OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы решили писать сразу на Unity не изучив основы языка C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли указать тип данных функции `OnTriggerEnter2D` — к таковым относятся, например, `int`, `float`, `void` и прочее. В Вашем же случае стоит проставить `void`:

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        onGround = True;
    }
    else{
        onGround = False;
    }
}
```